# Extjs : Validation for Integers

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I want to add a field which can take only integers and not decimal number.

I tried with numberfield as

```
{
    xtype : 'numberfield',
    fieldLabel : 'number',
}
```

i don't want to make it uneditable

is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try setting the [allowDecimals](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-cfg-allowDecimals) config on the numberfield, so that it looks like:

```
{
    xtype : 'numberfield',
    fieldLabel : 'number',
    allowDecimals: false
}
```